# JS script does not work in Safari Web Extension [Xcode]

Tags: javascript, xcode, safari-extension

I have a problem with my JS code not working in safari web Extensions.
[image].
I tried putting the code in popup.js and in content.js.

I expected the same thing as in this guide – https://myrusakov.ru/js-tabs.html. I just wanted to implement a system of tabs, but because of the js does not work, please help!